# List of QLabel in PySide/Qt

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I am a newbie with PySide. I have a QGridlayout with QLabel's and I want to add/remove/update QLabel.

1. Is it possible to create QList of QLabel with PySide similar to Qt in C++? After I populate the QGridlayout with QLabel and I want to dynamically increase/decrease the number of items in QGridlayout.
2. Is QListWidget/QListWidgetItem only way to create list in PySide? Can it be used with QLabel/QPixmap?

Comment: 1. Why not just use a normal list or dict?

Comment: I don't need to create a list after all. I did not know that you can iterate through items in the layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Sure. The python code will look just like C++ would look, sans syntax adaptations.
2. No. You can use a `QStandardItemModel`, or a custom model. In addition, there's no point to creating `QLabel` delegates for model data, since all standard views handle images and pixmaps available from `Qt::DecorationRole`. If all you want is a list of images, even a custom model would be trivial.